# Inconsistent accessibility with abstract classes

Tags: c#, public, internal, protected, access-modifiers

I have an internal abstract class `InternalClassBase` and two (also internal) classes `InternalClass1` and `InternalClass2`, which inherit from `InternalClassBase`.

I also have a public abstract class `PublicClassBase` and two (also public) classes `PublicClass1` and `PublicClass2`, which inherit from `PublicClassBase`.

The `PublicClassBase` has a protected member `XXX` of type `InternalClassBase`, so both `PublicClass1` and `PublicClass2` can use it.

This is my code:

```
internal abstract class InternalClassBase { }
internal class InternalClass1 : InternalClassBase { }
internal class InternalClass2 : InternalClassBase { }

public abstract class PublicClassBase
{
    protected InternalClassBase XXX;  // this is where the error happens
}
public class PublicClass1 : PublicClassBase { }
public class PublicClass2 : PublicClassBase { }
```

Why can't `PublicClassBase` contain the `XXX` member in my example? I thought that `XXX` would only be visible within `PublicClassBase`, `PublicClass1` and `PublicClass2`, but not outside of it.

I also thought that I understand access modifiers, but obviously I don't :)

Edit - the error happens at declaration of XXX inside PublicClassBase, and the exception message is: Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'ClassLibrary2.InternalClassBase' is less accessible than field 'ClassLibrary2.PublicClassBase.XXX', but how can protected be more accessible then internal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine that in an assembly *other* than the one types from your example are declared, you declare class `PublicClass3` that inherits from `PublicClassBase`. The field `XXX` should be visible from `PublicClass3`, since it is protected, but the type of the field is internal, so at the same time, it should *not* be visible from `PublicClass3`.

Obviously, you cannot have both, hence the error.

You can solve this either by making your field `private`, or making `PublicClassBase` and its children `internal`.

Comment: The workaround is changing the member from `protected` to `internal`.

Answer (score 3):

Given an assembly provided by you to me, containing the classes above, I can go ahead and create a subclass of `PublicClassBase` in a different assembly which references yours.

In that class, I would have to implement your protected member `XXX` of type `InternalClassBase` - clearly I can't, because `InternalClassBase` is marked as `internal`.